# Divide each dimension with different number from a list in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have ndarray with the shape (3,3,3) and list with 3 numbers.

I want to divide the first dimension with the first number in the list, the second dimension with the second number and third dimension with the third number.

Example:

```
np.random.rand(3,3,3)

>>>array([[[0.90428811, 0.60637664, 0.45090308],
        [0.17400851, 0.49163535, 0.62370288],
        [0.58701608, 0.91207839, 0.69364496]],

       [[0.85290321, 0.85170489, 0.48792597],
        [0.02602198, 0.91088298, 0.14882673],
        [0.63354821, 0.21764451, 0.30760075]],

       [[0.64833375, 0.13583598, 0.50561519],
        [0.42832468, 0.91146014, 0.41627495],
        [0.71238947, 0.37868578, 0.05874898]]])
```

and the list:

```
lst=[0.215, 0.561,0.724]
```

I want the output result to be the results of this:

```
[0.90428811/0.215, 0.60637664/0.215, 0.45090308/0.215],
        [0.17400851/0.215, 0.49163535/0.215, 0.62370288/0.215],
        [0.58701608/0.215, 0.91207839/0.215, 0.69364496/0.215]],

[[0.85290321/0.561, 0.85170489/0.561, 0.48792597/0.561],
        [0.02602198/0.561, 0.91088298/0.561, 0.14882673/0.561],
        [0.63354821/0.561, 0.21764451/0.561, 0.30760075/0.561]],

 [[0.64833375/0.724, 0.13583598/0.724, 0.50561519/0.724],
        [0.42832468/0.724, 0.91146014/0.724, 0.41627495/0.724],
        [0.71238947/0.724, 0.37868578/0.724, 0.05874898/0.724]]])
```

I have tried to do something like this (arr is the ndarray):

```
nums=np.arange(3)

for n in nums:
    arr[i]=arr[i]/lst[i]
```

but got error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: You might be able to do this with [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this. It [broadcasts](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the `lst` array to have shape `(3, 1, 1)` which easily goes with the shape of `a`.

Note that `None` is simply an alias for `np.newaxis`.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(3,3,3)
lst = np.array([0.215, 0.561,0.724])

a / lst[:, None, None]
```

Comment: that worked! the obly thing i'm not sure I understood is how it doesn't divide all the dimensions with the numbers in lst, how does it know to "apply" it on the correct dimension

Comment: I attached the link to numpy broadcasting in my answer. It basically virtually copies elements to generate a `lst` array of shape `(3, 3, 3)` from `(3, 1, 1)` to perform elementwise division. You can look into the link to understand more about how broadcasting works with more examples. Feel free to ask for further clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use index broadcasting:

```py
a = np.random.rand(3,3,3)
res = a / lst[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```

The reason this works is that `lst[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]` generates an array with shape (3, 1, 1) and numpy expands any dimension of size one to the required size (by repeating the element) for many common operations. This process is called broadcasting.

So in our example here, for the division the result of `lst[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]` would be expanded to:

```
[[[0.215, 0.215, 0.215],
  [0.215, 0.215, 0.215],
  [0.215, 0.215, 0.215]],

 [[0.561, 0.561, 0.561],
  [0.561, 0.561, 0.561],
  [0.561, 0.561, 0.561]],

 [[0.724, 0.724, 0.724],
  [0.724, 0.724, 0.724],
  [0.724, 0.724, 0.724]]]
```

Note that this expansion is happening only conceptually and numpy will not allocate more memory just to fill it with the same value over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a so good looking solution (because of the `lst` declaration), but it works:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.rand(3,3,3)

arr = np.array([[[0.90428811, 0.60637664, 0.45090308],
        [0.17400851, 0.49163535, 0.62370288],
        [0.58701608, 0.91207839, 0.69364496]],

       [[0.85290321, 0.85170489, 0.48792597],
        [0.02602198, 0.91088298, 0.14882673],
        [0.63354821, 0.21764451, 0.30760075]],

       [[0.64833375, 0.13583598, 0.50561519],
        [0.42832468, 0.91146014, 0.41627495],
        [0.71238947, 0.37868578, 0.05874898]]])
        
lst = [[[0.215]], [[0.561]],[[0.724]]]

div = np.divide(arr, lst)

print(div)
```

The ouput will be:

```
[[[4.20599121 2.82035647 2.09722363]
  [0.80934191 2.28667605 2.90094363]
  [2.73030735 4.24222507 3.22625563]]

 [[1.52032658 1.51819053 0.86974326]
  [0.04638499 1.62367733 0.26528829]
  [1.12931945 0.38795813 0.54830793]]

 [[0.8954886  0.18761876 0.69836352]
  [0.59160867 1.25892285 0.5749654 ]
  [0.98396336 0.52304666 0.081145  ]]]
```